# iOS int names[] = {CTL_HW, HW_PHYSMEM} the return HW_PHYSMEM value is negative

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My code is as follows, it's working fine on old device eg: iPhone 6, iPhone7, but it's not working on **iPhone XS Max**, it's return **-378535936** on my **iPhone XS Max**. Does anyone know the reason?

any suggestion would be help, thanks.

```
+ (NSUInteger)getHWPHYSMEMValue {
    size_t size = sizeof(int);
    int results;
    int mib[2] = {CTL_HW, HW_PHYSMEM};
    sysctl(mib, 2, &results, &size, NULL, 0);
    return (NSUInteger) results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the memory size in a 32-bit signed integer.  If the memory is over 2 GB, you will get a negative value (and if over 4GB, it will be truncated and more-or-less random).

Try using HW_MEMSIZE which uses a uint64_t value.